# Rails 4 - Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have a profile model and an organisation model.

Profile.rb: belongs_to :organisation
Organisation.rb has_many :profiles.

My profile table has an attribute called :organisation_id.

In my profile show page, I want to show the name of the organisation that the profile belongs to.

I have:

```
                <%= @profile.organisation.try(:title) %>
```

In my profile form, I ask users to choose their organisation:

```
<%= f.association :organisation,
                     as: :check_boxes,
                     label_method: :title,
                     value_method: :id,
                     label: false  %>
```

When I try this, there are no errors showing, just that nothing shows in the show page in the place where the name of the organisation is supposed to be.

I am wondering if thats because I have to white label the organisation id in the profile model?

I tried adding:

```
organisation_id: [],
```

to my strong params in the profiles controller, but it didn't make any difference.

When I fill in the profile edit form, I can choose an organisation. I tick the box and expect to see its title in the profiles show page. It's blank.

When I go into the console and try:

```
o = Organisation.where(profile_id:9)
```

It gives this error:

```
  Organisation Load (6.1ms)  SELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."profile_id" = 9
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column organisations.profile_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisat...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."profile_id" = 9
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column organisations.profile_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisat...
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Vishal's suggestion:

```
Organisation.includes(:profiles).where(:profile => {:id => 9})
SyntaxError: (irb):55: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
...s.map(&:table_name)Organisation.includes(:profiles).where(:p...
```

Peter's suggestion:

```
Organisation.where(profile_ids: [9])
  Organisation Load (35.5ms) 
SELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."profile_ids" = 9
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column organisations.profile_ids does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisat...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."profile_ids" = 9
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column organisations.profile_ids does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisat...
```

Peter's suggestion adapted (to make profile_id singular rather than plural):

```
Organisation.where(profile_id: [9])
  Organisation Load (36.9ms)  SELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."profile_id" = 9
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column organisations.profile_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisat...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."profile_id" = 9
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column organisations.profile_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "organisations".* FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisat...
```

Vishal's next suggestion:

```
Organisation.includes(:profiles).where(:profiles => {:id => 9})
  SQL (18.9ms)  SELECT "organisations"."id" AS t0_r0, "organisations"."title" AS t0_r1, "organisations"."logo" AS t0_r2, "organisations"."banner" AS t0_r3, "organisations"."org_type" AS t0_r4, "organisations"."email_format" AS t0_r5, "organisations"."website" AS t0_r6, "organisations"."formal_name" AS t0_r7, "organisations"."company_number" AS t0_r8, "organisations"."jurisdiction_of_incorporation" AS t0_r9, "organisations"."onboarded" AS t0_r10, "organisations"."cf_docs" AS t0_r11, "organisations"."user_id" AS t0_r12, "organisations"."created_at" AS t0_r13, "organisations"."updated_at" AS t0_r14, "organisations"."abn" AS t0_r15, "profiles"."id" AS t1_r0, "profiles"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "profiles"."title" AS t1_r2, "profiles"."hero" AS t1_r3, "profiles"."overview" AS t1_r4, "profiles"."occupation" AS t1_r5, "profiles"."external_profile" AS t1_r6, "profiles"."working_languages" AS t1_r7, "profiles"."created_at" AS t1_r8, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t1_r9, "profiles"."organisation_id" AS t1_r10 FROM "organisations" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."organisation_id" = "organisations"."id" WHERE "profiles"."id" = $1  [["id", 9]]
```

TAKING PETER'S ANSWER BELOW,

I make my profile controller show action:

```
  def show
    @profile = Profile.includes(:industries).find(params[:id])
    @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:organisation_id])
    @profiles = @organisation.profiles
  end
```

When I save that and try again, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show
Couldn't find Organisation with 'id'=

Extracted source (around line #17): - it points to this line:
    @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:organisation_id])
```

Comment: Hey in your organisation table there is no column with name `profile_id` and  you putted condition on this column in `where` clause so giving you this issue

Comment: Hi Vishal, but why do I need to put profile_id in Org, when profile belongs to Org?

Comment: yes no need to put profile_id there but you can selecting this way so. other wise you can write query like `Organisation.includes(:profiles).where(:profiles => {:id => 9})`

Comment: A profile has an organization_id, an organization has profile_ids according to your associations. The value in your form should be organization_id instead of id. In your example query it would be: Organization.where(profile_ids: [9]), but you actually want: Profile.where(organization_id: params[:organization_id])

Comment: @VishalJAIN no, OP does not need `profile_id` column in `organisations` table, only `organization_id` on `profiles`

Comment: Hi Peter. My associations are: profile: belongs_to organisation. Organisation: has many profiles. I want to show the organisation that a profile belongs to on the profile show page.

Comment: I'll set out each of my attempts to try the above suggestions and the error messages I get above

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yes i just explain him what is the error. doesn't recommend to add this column.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I tried your suggestion but get the error I posted above. I can't follow what you've done to try and link the models

Comment: user: First you set the organization_id in your form. Next your controller action does two things: organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id]) followed by @profiles = organization.profiles. P.s. I'm on my mobile now, but I could show an example in about 15 min or so.

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm not sure how to follow this idea at all. I'm afraid I don't understand that. Do you think I need to write lines like that somewhere in my organisation controller / my profile controller/somewhere else??

Comment: @user2860931 can you please put complete error here and replace it by following `Organisation.includes(:profiles).where(:profiles => {:id => 9})` because you have put table name as `profile` instead of `profiles`

Comment: Hi Vishal - I just tried that line in the console. I copied the output. I've never seen anything like it. I' don't know what it's doing and I don't know how to show the organisation.title for the profile where the profile_id = 9.

Comment: @user2860931 records are return or not?? if not then no organisation attach to given profile. you can show organization title by `@organisations.first.title`

Comment: Hi Vishan, in the form, I picked org with id: 5. I'm expecting the title of that org to display as a result of the search. When I typed what you suggested in the console, I got the output I posted above (which is really odd to me -I've never seen anything like it).

Comment: The oddness you see is because you use includes. It preloads all profiles, so you dont have to query when you call profile.id etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem arose because the form input field was asking for a check box. That was a problem because it expected an array of inputs (when there can only be one organisation per profile). When I remove the checkbox requirement, the form input element turns into a select list. Then the submit works to save the organisation and the title displays correctly.